# geckodriver windows authentication

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

I am upgrading my tests to use Selenium 3.4.0.  Running the test with the latest chrome driver I have no problems, when I configure the tests to use geckodriver I receive a windows Authentication Required dialog:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRSTH.png)

Here is my configuration for the FirefoxDriver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./drivers/geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

The console output shows the following:

```
1498596765531   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:40330
1498596766187   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser \\?
\C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-
marionette"]
:
 no] Stack trace: FileUtils_getDir()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:70 
< FileUtils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 < 
validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:674 < 
startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:837 < 
startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3145 < 
observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:65
1498596767838   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 50529
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2572: 
NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
Jun 27, 2017 1:52:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

I am not sure why I am getting this javascript error:

```
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2572: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
```

Any reason why the geckodriver is causing the windows authentication dialog to appear?

The website is an internal application that use kerberos for authentication.

Comment: Please post versions of geckodriver and firefox browser. Also, why are you mixing chromedriver and firefox (first line)?

Comment: GeckoDriver v16.1 and Firefox 54.0. MikeJRamesey56, sorry to cause confusion, copy and paste error :). I edited my post above.

Comment: Can you try with Gecko v0.17.0. It mentions this - "Increasing the length of the network.http.phishy-userpass-length preference will cause Firefox to not prompt when navigating to a website with a username or password in the URL". Haven't tried it though

Comment: I upgraded to gecko driver v0.18.0, and the issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by upgrading to Selenium 3.6.0, and then passing the following preferences to the driver:

```
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
String sitelist = "mydomain.com, https://myotherdomain.com";
ffprofile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.force-enable",true);
ffprofile.setPreference("network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris", sitelist);
ffprofile.setPreference("network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris", sitelist);
ffprofile.setPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", sitelist);
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(ffprofile);
```