# GeckoFX45 Crash With System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, firefox, geckofx

I want to test GeckoFX with the Zoom link. But it throws "System.AccessViolationException" in Program.cs

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Gecko;

namespace GeckoFXTest
{
    public partial class webbrowser : Form
    {
        public webbrowser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Initialize();
        }
        public GeckoWebBrowser browser;
        private void Initialize()
        {
            browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
            Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Navigate("https://us04web.zoom.us/j/...?pwd=...");
            browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
        }
        private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Window.Document.Title);
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Window.Document.Uri);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Browser opens this page]

When I click the "Launch Meeting" button, sometimes it closing with nothing but sometimes it throws "System.AccessViolationException" error.

Note: In first try, it opened Launch App window. I don't check "Always Ask" and clicked "Allow" button and opened Zoom. It didn't work after that.

Tried:

- Reinstall GeckoFX
- Removing Debug folder.
- Changing AnyCPU to x86.
- Clearing Temp folders.
- Restarting Visual Studio with ADMIN priveleges.

Comment: Did you open you browser and delete history?  Your browser options are used also by Net.  Can you manually go to webpage in your browswer?

Comment: I deleted history and manually go to the webpage but it didn't work.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789965/geckodriver-windows-authentication

Comment: It didn't work. I tried to add preferences and version downgrade.

Comment: You are using https (secure) which uses TLS.  You need to use a version of GECKO which supports the TLS version.  Downgrade probably won't work since you can only use TLS 1.2 and 1.3 and downgrading is probably using TLS 1.0 or 1.1.

Comment: Ok. Now, I'm using the latest version of Gecko. What do you think is the problem? Like I said it was working on the first try. What could be causing problem?

Comment: Server may not allow two connections from same client so connection may not be closing.  A memory leak maybe?

Comment: Can I get the internal URL for the start app with "Process.Start()" ?

Comment: From cmd.exe >Netstat -a

Comment: No. When login into the website, sends a parameter (ex: zoommtg:...) to "Zoom.exe" and the meeting starts. I want to get this and start the meeting by "Process.Start()".

Link changes every try.

Comment: You would need Admin rights on both local and remote machines and start VS by right click and select Run As Admin.  So it would be the same as running an app from cmd.exe on a remote machine.  You would need to also use the $ to grant admin rights.  I probably would do this by creating a bat file on local machine and first test the bat before trying in c#.

Comment: But when I open the zoom link from Opera or other browsers, it writes "Launched external handler for 'zoommtg://us04web.zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=...&pwd=...&zc=0&mcv=...&confid=...&browser=opera&t=1610633696551'." to console. And Cefsharp contains a method for this (RequestHandler).

I searched this handler for Gecko but can't find it anymore.

Comment: zoommtg is a protocol like http or ftp.  See : https://devforum.zoom.us/t/parameters-in-zoomus-and-zoommtg-protocol-to-start-internet-audio/24099

Comment: Thanks, but I should get the dynamic link from zoom. So, the zoommtg link changes every time. The browser should get the link after the webpage loaded.

Comment: Any dynamic link should be handled by the protocol.  You are probably going to a login page and then after you login you are being forwarded to a meeting page which is a parameter in the URL.  Anything after the question mark in a URL are parameters..

Comment: The website generates a key for the meeting. And the URL not contains the key. Has GeckoFx a RequestHandler method like Cefsharp?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area.  Gecko is a browser and zoommtg is a protocol (like http).  Did you download zoommtg?  The version you have may not be compatible with Gecko.  I think I would delete zoommtg then with Gecko Browser go to zoommtg.  You probably will be get asked to download zoommtg. Once you get working manually then try again with c# code.

Comment: Yeah, I have zoommtg app. As I already said on my first try Gecko opened a popup page named "Launch App". I uncheck "Always Ask" and clicked "Start" button.

Comment: TRy setting UserAgent to "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/304b1fd8-d2d0-40e9-9bd1-f804c6685ece/how-to-set-useragent-in-winform-app-outside-of-webbrowser-control?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: Something happened. I tried a few user agents. And in mobile agents, it give a error contains "zoomus app can't opening." I think Zoom using zoomus protocol in mobile agents. And the problem is zoommtg protocol. Crashes on every link that starts with "zoommtg".

Comment: Do you work with Postaman.  See : https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/guides/postman/using-postman-to-test-zoom-apis.  Then same Postman settings should be used in c#.

Comment: I tried a few websites, they all crashed the app. Don't think the problem caused by Zoom.

Comment: Isn't zoom the common denominator?  I mean the zoom driver.

Comment: Actually, I tried Zoom for testing GeckoFx. After Zoom, the website that opened any external application did not work. I should open an external app on any website without any problem.

Comment: Are you using latest version (32bit 64 bit)? : https://www.nuget.org/profiles/geckofx

Comment: Yes, I installed the latest version from NuGet. And running the app with 32 bit.

Comment: Do zoom work with another browser?  I think there is a compatibilty issue.

Comment: I'm using Zoom with other browsers (Opera, Edge, etc.) and there is no problem.

Comment: There are zoom updates here : https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/changelog